# Selenium + WSL 2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wsl-2

I am trying to set up python selenium to work on my WSL 2 (Kali).
I have followed along with this article https://www.gregbrisebois.com/posts/chromedriver-in-wsl2/

Running "google-chrome" in terminal returns a working browser.

Trying to run this test script results in a browser window, but nothing loads into the window and no code after driver = webdriver.Chrome() runs.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

print('starting')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

print('Worked')
driver.close()
```

This is the browser the script returns but never stops loading
[image]

Comment: I would check browser and chromedriver versions to see if they match.

Comment: @pcalkins they do not match... was not aware.  I am using chrome 90.0.4430.93 and webdriver version 89.0.4389.114

Comment: @pcalkins this solved my issue thank you